# d3 x axis won't fit on svg

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js

I have a d3 x axis and I want it to start at 2020 (to represent this year) and increase in years until some maximum year and fit into the svg.

I make a scale by passing an accessor function and a range like so:

```
 var scX = makeScale( d => d["x"], [currentYear, currentYear + maxYear] );
```

and this moves the axis into the DOM when I change the start value of the range to the currentYear - pxX, where pxX is the svg width, but the x axis is still shifted way over to the right.

Then I translate the x axis over to the left by the width of the svg like so:

```
 svg.append( "g" )
.attr( "transform", "translate(" + -pxX + "," + pxY/2 + ")")
```

but it still isn't correct and the x axis still doesn't fit inside the svg?

Here is my complete code - as you can see I'm using React Hooks for my framework:

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [currentYear, setCurrentYear] = useState(2020);
  const [maxYear, setMaxYear] = useState(30);
  const [data, setData] = useState(
    [
      {x: 2020, y1: 0.001, y2: 0.63},
      {x: 2027, y1: 0.003, y2: 0.84},
      {x: 2031, y1: 0.024, y2: 0.56},
      {x: 2035, y1: 0.054, y2: 0.22},
      {x: 2040, y1: 0.062, y2: 0.15},
      {x: 2050, y1: 0.062, y2: 0.15}
    ]
  );

  const initialiseData = () => {
    var svg = d3.select( "svg" );

    var pxX = svg.attr( "width" );
    var pxY = svg.attr( "height" );

    var makeScale = function( accessor, range ) {
      console.log("RANGE", accessor, range)
      return d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain( d3.extent( data, accessor ) )
        .range( range )
        .nice()
    }

    var scX = makeScale( d => d["x"], [currentYear - pxX, currentYear + maxYear] );

    svg.append( "g" )
    .attr( "transform", "translate(" + -pxX + "," + pxY/2 + ")")
    .call( d3.axisTop( scX ).tickValues(
      data.map(function(d) { return d.x; })
    ))
}

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      initialiseData();
    }

  }, [data])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <svg id="demo1" width="1200" height="400" style={{background: "lightgrey"}}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How do I make sure the x axis is always centred in the svg and I can see the start and end values?

Comment: Ah! ok that solves it!